# Which TeX-Live package contains "ly1enc.def"?

Tags: font-encodings, texlive-2017

I am distributing a LaTeX package containing templates for our organization. I am developing on Windows and we have an automated build process established for Linux, which also does some basic testing. On a recent change, an error message came up:

```
   ! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `ly1enc.def' not found.
   (fontenc)                You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.
```

While I thought the encoding definitions come by default, my issue is, how can I find out which additional package I need to define in the dependencies, so it works again? We are working with `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)` and the packages defined as dependencies are:

1. `texlive-latex-recommended`
2. `texlive-latex-extra`
3. `texlive-lang-german`
4. `texlive-fonts-recommended`
5. `texlive-science`

I have no way of accessing a machine that runs this Linux right now, so it would be good to have a way finding this out through repositories. But I would also accept an alternative which requires access to a machine running that config.

Comment: You might want to rephrase that title so something like which Debian TeXLive packages contains `ly1enc.def`

Comment: It might be in the Debian package: `texlive-fonts-extra` (found via `apt-file search ly1enc.def`)

Comment: Thanks @dalaif, I think that's it and currently wait for a rebuild, to confirm.

Comment: I manage a similar package and just lists the required packages and files in the manual. Then users will have to sort it out them self

Comment: @daleif well I think it prevents Support requests requiring my answer. And due the automatic build&test on a Jenkins I need to provide it anyway, otherwise Jenkins will tell me it failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tlmgr info ly1enc.def`

will report that it is part of the `ly1` package

and

`tlmgr info ly1`

reports that that package is part of the `collection-fontsextra`

```
$ tlmgr info ly1
package:     ly1
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Support for LY1 LaTeX encoding
longdesc:    The Y&Y 'texnansi' (TeX and ANSI, for Microsoft interpretations of ANSI standards) encoding lives on, even after the decease of the company; it is known in the LaTeX scheme of things as LY1 encoding. This bundle includes metrics and LaTeX macros to use the basic three (Times, Helvetica and Courier) Adobe Type 1 fonts in LaTeX using LY1 encoding.
installed:   Yes
revision:    47848
sizes:       doc: 9k, run: 417k
relocatable: No
cat-license: lppl
cat-topics:  font-supp
collection:  collection-fontsextra
```

---

As you are using thedebian packaged texlive you need an apt package which is `texlive-fonts-extra`

Comment: I just notice you are using debian packaged texlive, will add an answer for that shortly

Comment: Given that the OP lists something like `texlive-latex-recommended` they might not have a usable `tlmgr` at least it might not list which Debuan texlive package provides the file (at least that is how I interpret the OPs question).

Comment: @daleif yes just noticed OP is using debian see above comment that crossed with yours

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle indeed it is Debian, thought the debug info ```TeX Live 2017/Debian``` is enough info. However as I found a great answer in another question, I marked this as duplicate. The link that helped me was: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents

Comment: @TobiBS ah I was looking for that dup, but I added the package name here as well, for completeness:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and so you win the answered checkmark. ;-)